# looping through an array of pointers and calling method gives access violation

Tags: c++

I've been trying to debug this for a few hours now, but I'm at the point I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting the error `exited with code=3221225477` trying to iterate through an array of pointers `classRosterArray[i]->print();` in my `Roster.cpp` class with the `printAll()` function.

After doing a quick Google search on that exit code, I got [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53369553/11110509) that says:

> 3221225477 converted to hex is 0xC0000005, which stands for STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, which means you tried to access (read, write or execute) invalid memory.

But even with that answer, I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.

In my main method:

```
int main()
{
    int *arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = 2;
    arr[1] = 21;
    arr[2] = 34;
    Student s("5", "David", "Smith", "davidsmith@gmail.com", 25, arr, DegreeProgram::SECURITY);
    
    const string studentData[] =
        {
            "A1,John,Smith,John1989@gm ail.com,20,30,35,40,SECURITY",
            "A2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,50,30,40,NETWORK",
            "A3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,20,40,33,SOFTWARE",
            "A4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,50,58,40,SECURITY",
            "A5,Suzy,Smith,suzysmith@ubc.edu,21,21,21,21,SOFTWARE"};

    Roster *r = new Roster(studentData, 5);
    r->add("A6", "David", "Smith", "dsmith@gmail.com", 21, 21, 21, 21, DegreeProgram::NETWORK);
    
    r->printAll(); //All of my debugging has led to this method which is causing the status code error.
    //If I remove printAll() my program runs with no issue

    return 0;
}
```

All I'm doing is iterating through the array of pointers and calling the `print()` method from my student class.

It works fine when I call the `print()` method in the constructor `//classRosterArray[i] -> print();`. Not sure why it's not working when I call `printAll();`

Inside my `roster.cpp` class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "roster.h"

#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

Roster::Roster(const string studentData[], int currentRosterSize)
{
    this->currentRosterSize = currentRosterSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentRosterSize; i++)
    {
        string singleStudentString = studentData[i];
        vector<string> result;
        stringstream s_stream(singleStudentString);
        while (s_stream.good())
        {
            string substr;
            getline(s_stream, substr, ',');
            result.push_back(substr);
        }

        string studentId;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string emailAddress;
        int age;
        int daysToCompleteCourse1;
        int daysToCompleteCourse2;
        int daysToCompleteCourse3;
        DegreeProgram degreeProgram;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 0:
                studentId = result.at(i);
                break;

            case 1:
                firstName = result.at(i);
                break;

            case 2:
                lastName = result.at(i);
                break;

            case 3:
                emailAddress = result.at(i);
                break;

            case 4:
                age = std::stoi(result.at(i));
                break;

            case 5:
                daysToCompleteCourse1 = std::stoi(result.at(i));
                break;

            case 6:
                daysToCompleteCourse2 = std::stoi(result.at(i));
                break;

            case 7:
                daysToCompleteCourse3 = std::stoi(result.at(i));
                break;

            case 8:
                if (result.at(i) == "SECURITY")
                {
                    degreeProgram = SECURITY;
                }
                else if (result.at(i) == "NETWORK")
                {
                    degreeProgram = NETWORK;
                }
                else if (result.at(i) == "SOFTWARE")
                {
                    degreeProgram = SOFTWARE;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        
        }

        int *arr = new int[3];
        arr[0] = daysToCompleteCourse1;
        arr[1] = daysToCompleteCourse2;
        arr[2] = daysToCompleteCourse3;

        classRosterArray[i] = new Student(studentId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, arr, degreeProgram);
        //classRosterArray[i] -> print();
    }
}

void Roster::add(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse1,
                 int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degreeProgram)
{
    
    int arrNumDaysInCourse[3] = {daysInCourse1, daysInCourse2, daysInCourse3};
    currentRosterSize++;
    classRosterArray[currentRosterSize] = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, arrNumDaysInCourse, degreeProgram);
    cout << "Add method called. " << classRosterArray[currentRosterSize]->getFirstName();
}

void Roster::remove(string studentId)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < currentRosterSize; i++)
    {
        if (classRosterArray[i]->getId() == studentId)
        {
            currentRosterSize--;
            classRosterArray[i] = classRosterArray[currentRosterSize];
            cout << "Found student with id: " << studentId << " . Removing student from roster.";
            break;
        }

        if (i == currentRosterSize - 1)
        {
            cout << "No student found with id: " << studentId;
        }
    }
}

void Roster::printAll()
{
            //This is causing the error code. I have no clue why this is causing it :/
            
    for (int i = 0; i < currentRosterSize; i++)
    {
        classRosterArray[i]->print();
    }
}
```

My `student.cpp` class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"

Student::Student(){
    
}

Student::Student(string id, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age,
                 int* arrDaysToCompleteCourse, DegreeProgram degreeProgram)
{
        this->id = id;
        this->firstName = firstName;
        this->lastName = lastName;
        this->emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this->age = age;
        this->arrDaysToCompleteCourse = arrDaysToCompleteCourse;
        this->degreeProgram = degreeProgram;
}

//Setter methods
void Student::setId(string id)
{
    this->id = id;
}

void Student::setFirstName(string firstName)
{
    this->firstName = firstName;
}

void Student::setLastName(string lastName)
{
    this->lastName = lastName;
}

void Student::setEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
{
    this->emailAddress = emailAddress;
}

void Student::setAge(int age)
{
    this->age = age;
}

void Student::setNumDaysToCompleteCourse(int *arrDaysToCompleteCourse)
{
    this->arrDaysToCompleteCourse = arrDaysToCompleteCourse;
}

void Student::setDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeProgram)
{
    this->degreeProgram = degreeProgram;
}

//Getter methods
string Student::getId()
{
    return id;
}

string Student::getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

string Student::getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

string Student::getEmailAddress()
{
    return emailAddress;
}

int Student::getAge()
{
    return age;
}

int *Student::getNumDaysToCompleteCourse()
{
    return arrDaysToCompleteCourse;
}

DegreeProgram Student::getDegreeProgram()
{
    return degreeProgram;
}

//Print method
void Student::print()
{
    cout << id << "\t";
    cout << "First Name: " << firstName << "\t";
    cout << "Last Name: " << lastName << "\t";
    //cout << "Email address: " << emailAddress << "\n";
    cout << "Age: " << age << "\t";
    cout << "Number days to complete courses: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUM_COURSES; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0){
            cout << "{";
        }

        cout << arrDaysToCompleteCourse[i];

        if (i != TOTAL_NUM_COURSES - 1)
        {
            cout << ", ";
        }

        if(i == TOTAL_NUM_COURSES - 1){
            cout << "}\t";
        }
    }

    cout << "Degree program: ";

    if (degreeProgram == SECURITY)
    {
        cout << "Security";
    }
    else if (degreeProgram == NETWORK)
    {
        cout << "Network";
    }
    else if (degreeProgram == SOFTWARE)
    {
        cout << "Software";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Undefined program";
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

Student.h file:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <string>
#include <array>
#include "degree.h"
using namespace std;

class Student
{

private:
    string id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string emailAddress;
    int age;
    int *arrDaysToCompleteCourse;
    DegreeProgram degreeProgram;
    const int TOTAL_NUM_COURSES = 3;

public:
    Student();
    Student(string id, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int *arrDaysToCompleteCourse, DegreeProgram degreeProgram);

    void setId(string id);
    void setFirstName(string firstName);
    void setLastName(string setLastName);
    void setEmailAddress(string setEmailAddress);
    void setAge(int setAge);
    void setNumDaysToCompleteCourse(int *arrDaysToCompleteCourse);
    void setDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeProgram);

    string getId();
    string getFirstName();
    string getLastName();
    string getEmailAddress();
    int getAge();
    int *getNumDaysToCompleteCourse();
    DegreeProgram getDegreeProgram();

    void print();
};

#endif
```

Roster.h file:

```
#ifndef ROSTER_H
#define ROSTER_H

#include <string>
#include <array>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

class Roster
{

private:
    Student **classRosterArray;
    int currentRosterSize;

public:
    Roster(const string studentData[], int currentRosterSize);

    void add(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse1,
             int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degreeprogram);

    void remove(string studentID);

    void printAll();

    void printAverageDaysInCourse(string studentID);

    void printInvalidEmails();

    void printByDegreeProgram(DegreeProgram degreeProgram);
};

#endif
```

Comment: If you provide code samples, please boil them down to the relevant lines to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please run your code under a debugger. It should crash and give you a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: Also, please include the declarations of your Roster and Student class. Don't make us reverse engineer your class declarations. Perhaps the issue is that `classRosterArray` is a fixed size and you're writing past the end of the array? There's definitely an issue with passing the address of the local `arrNumDaysInCourse` to the `Student` constructor in `Roster::add`.

Comment: I don't see any code here that is allocating memory for the `classRosterArray` array, so it makes sense that any code that tries to access it is likely going to crash. I also see several memory leaks in this code, too. The code shown is not a [mcve], it needs to be trimmed down or rewritten to eliminate unnecessary logic to reproduce the problem.

Comment: does the commented-out line `classRosterArray[i] -> print();` work?

Comment: @user253751 yes that line in the constructor works when I uncomment it and do not call the ```printAll()``` function. ```.add() also works```